# FillRect with WHITE_BRUSH fails on WinCE 6.0

Tags: windows, windows-ce, win32gui

I'm attempting to clear part of my screen with

```
FillRect(hdc, &r, (HBRUSH)(WHITE_BRUSH))
```

However it "succeeds" (returns nonzero) but writes nothing to the screen. If I change it to

```
FillRect(hdc, &r, (HBRUSH)(WHITE_BRUSH+1))
```

it magically starts working, except now it's clearing the screen with a slight gray color. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brush constants are not guaranteed to be valid handles; you're supposed to use [`GetStockObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921556.aspx) to convert the constant to a handle. It's probably just a coincidence that `WHITE_BRUSH+1` evaluates to something that appears to work.